# Python program slows down as number of processes grows. Why? How to overcome?

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, python-multiprocessing

I have a dumb piece of code (blah.py) that simply does some CPU load:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    while True:
        startTime = perf_counter()

        primes = []
        for possiblePrime in range(2, 40000):

            # Assume number is prime until shown it is not.
            isPrime = True
            for num in range(2, possiblePrime):
                if possiblePrime % num == 0:
                    isPrime = False
                    break

            if isPrime:
                primes.append(possiblePrime)

        print(f'Took {perf_counter() - startTime}s')
```

Then I just run it in several shells simultaneously, like: `cmd python.exe blah.py`

I can see that execution time depends on number of started processes.

```
proc. #  time
1        8.9s
2        9.6s
4        11.1s
8        17.3s
```

Same symptoms when using process Pool etc.

The system: Windows 10 64bit, CPU i7 4 cores (8 logical), 8GB RAM, Python 3.6.3 |Anaconda custom (64-bit)| (default, Oct 15 2017, 03:27:45) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32

Why python program behaves this way?
May be some sort of hidden inter-process communication happens, or any kind of global lock I don't aware of (GIL, really?) or may be an exotic Anaconda setting for python environment.

How to overcome such an issue?

Thanks in advance to everyone responded.

P.S. When run some real code on a 32 core server - performance drops dramatically.

Comment: where are the processes? are they really processes, or threads??

Comment: Parallelization doesn't magically get you more CPU. It offers performance improvements for tasks which *aren't* CPU bound.

Comment: it's not related to python or multiprocessing module. When you have reached the CPU limit, launching more processes just makes it worse because of context switching and possibly memory swapping

Comment: FYI: you don't need to check up to the number itself to see if it is a factor, iirc you can get away with testing up to sqrt(possiblePrime) for factors. Also this might be relevant to your issue: [Amdahl's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law)

Comment: before running 700 processes with some code, optimize the code itself...

Comment: I want to run as much processes as number of CPU cores. With that said, I believe it's a fear expectation to have x-times faster execution and true parallelism. What I don't understand, why it doesn't work this way.

Comment: @tripleee: of course it offers better performance for CPU-bound problems, *especially in python*. otherwise you could just go with threads.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre: obviously he's doing it for the practice, so he doesn't want to optimize the code.

Comment: @blue_note Sure, you can increase CPU utilization; but once the cores are fully loaded, any additional parallel processes will only add overhead as well as cause congestion.

Comment: @tripleee: of course, but in a normal developer machine (usually not running anything else heavy), decreasing performance with 4 processes seems kind of weird.

Comment: Some Windows stupidity tax? https://superuser.com/questions/1172595/force-windows-to-use-all-cores